PAM authentication fails despite the right password
I am trying to use PAM for authentication:
// gcc [file] -lstdc++ -lpam -lpam_misc
#include <iostream>
#include <security/pam_appl.h> 
#include <security/pam_misc.h>

int main()
{
    const char * username = "********";
    const char * password = "********";
    const char * data[] = {username, password};

    struct pam_conv pconv = {misc_conv, data};
    struct pam_handle *phandle = NULL;
    int result;

    result = pam_start("display_manager", username, &pconv, &phandle);
    std::cout << "pam_start: " << pam_strerror(phandle, result) << "\n";

    result = pam_authenticate(phandle, 0);
    std::cout << "pam_authenticate: " << pam_strerror(phandle, result) << "\n";
}

However it fails with no helpful error message (it just says "Authentication failed") despite me providing the right password.
Here is my journalctl (i replaced username and host name with ********):
Oct 08 19:50:26 ******** main[42928]: pam_warn(display_manager:auth): function=[pam_sm_authenticate] flags=0 service=[display_manager] terminal=[<unknown>] user=[********] ruser=[<unknown>] rhost=[<unknown>]
Oct 08 19:50:26 ******** main[42928]: PAM pam_close_session: NULL pam handle passed
Oct 08 19:50:26 ******** main[42928]: PAM pam_setcred: NULL pam handle passed
Oct 08 19:50:26 ******** main[42928]: PAM pam_end: NULL pam handle passed


@WitHol you just forgot to put your username, instead of those "*********" I assume. It works perfectly for me

@Mike i did not, I changed all of my usernames and passwords to ******** here, but it's the right username in the original code

Do you have /etc/pam.d/display_manager with properly configured auth service? Do you run the program as root?

Furthermore, misc_conv() is not supposed to authenticate with externally supplied password. It is supposed to ask user to enter a password. For authenticating with pre-defined password you should provide your own conversation function which allocates struct pam_response, fills it with pointer to allocated password string and returns it via response argument.

@WitHol - Make sure you have put your username correctly (username and not your fullname). Otherwise you might try reinstall PAM API. On latest debian it's libpam0g-dev I believe

You are not writing the authorization module correctly! The password is checked in the pam_sm_authenticate function and in it you must implement the verification of your password. If it is correct, then return " PAM_SUCCESS" or "PAM_AUTH_ERR".
There cannot be a "main" function in your program. This is not an executable file, but a module. I suggest you look at my written module and how it is compiled.
https://github.com/oditynet/2fact-telegram
For example logical from my project:
pin= converse(pamh, PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF, "Please enter the PIN: "); 
    if (atoi(pin) == 12345)
    {
        return PAM_SUCCESS;
    }
    return PAM_AUTH_ERR ;

